# How to copy data from a BigQuery Connector Sheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

Is there a way to write an Apps Script to copy data from a sheet that is a BigQuery Data Connector Sheet to another sheet?

I have a connector the runs a query in BigQuery, inputting a table. I want to copy this entire table to another sheet in that same workbook.

Below is the type of code I've tried but I get an error "Exception: The action is not supported for DATASOURCE sheet."

```
function copyData() {
  var sourceSheetNames = ["Connector Sheet 1", "Connector Sheet 2"];
  var targetSheetName = "Sheet1";
  var targetCellStartRow = [3, 16];
  var targetCellStartColumn = 1;
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < sourceSheetNames.length; i++) {
    var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetNames[i]);
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetCellStartRow[i], targetCellStartColumn, sourceRange.getNumRows(), sourceRange.getNumColumns());
    
    sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you should consider using workflows as mentioned here in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/write-to-google-sheets#deploy-workflow)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).